# "Pictures of the drivers licences of your drivers" or "pictures of the drivers licences for your drivers"?

Tags: prepositions

Could you please tell me which sentence below sounds more natural and grammatical?

> For us to be able to see what your insurance premium is going to look lile, we need pictures of the drivers licenses **of** your drivers.
>
> For us to be able to see what your insurance premium is going to look lile, we need pictures of the drivers licenses **for** your drivers.

I would have thought that *of* is the only correct option there, but I've noticed that insurance agents use *for* in such contexts.

Can both *of* and *for* be use in the context and are perfectly natural?

Comment: Pictures of your drivers' licenses. License for *what* is obvious from the context.

Comment: I would say that either is fine; 'of' focuses on possession, 'for' focuses on official registration.

Comment: Both are wordy, often a benefit to the insurer. "To set your premiums, we must cover every driver in your household. Please scan every license."

Comment: I've downvoted because you've given us a choice between two sub-optimal ways of saying this, when there are better ways. For example: "We will need a photocopy of the drivers license(s) held by each driver employed by your company".

Comment: @Weather Vane: That isn't the same thing, as it implies there is only one driver. As I understand the sample question they are contemplating the possibility of covering multiple drivers on a single policy.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir **drivers' licenses** implies *more than* one driver. Both those words are plural. As TimR wrote, neither of the OP's offerings are great.

Comment: @TimR, I didn't make up the sentence with "for." I hear sentences with "for" used often by agents whose native language is English

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a meaningless choice between two sub-optimal ways of saying something. Obviously *neither* would be the competent native Anglophone's choice here.

Comment: The sentence is offering auto coverage. "Pictures of the drivers' licenses **for** your drivers" is to pay for coverage **for** them. They don't care about the licences of your drivers.

Comment: Why not take it as a challenge to make it even more confusing? "We need your drivers' driver's license's pictures"

Comment: @TimR In all seriousness though, this seems to be missing the point of the question. It's not about best wording, it's about a specific use of "for." And while I'm having trouble finding a dictionary entry to back me up, I *do* hear this usage. I would interpret it less as "belonging to" and more as "relating to," as in "Hi school administrator, thanks for getting us registered; here's the vaccination record *for* my son and the birth certificate *for* my daughter."

Comment: "For" means that the licences apply to the drivers; "of" means they are in the possession or belong to the drivers. There isn't a necessary difference but it depends on the precise details of what licences are required for a particular purpose. You could imagine a situation where a company held documentation stating that one or more employees were allowed to do something, and if the documentation was owned and maintained by the company, then "for" would be correct. Even in other circumstances "for" emphasises that the licences must cover all the drivers.

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope  If you rephrase your question to ask whether either preposition could be used,  I will retract the close vote.

Comment: @AndyBonner You're right.  I was focusing on "which sentence".

Comment: "For each of your drivers please provide a photograph of his or her driver's licence" is OK in how *for* is used. It is when the "for" phrase is put at the back that the possible problem arises. I don't think there is a real problem; I am quite happy to accept the insurance agent's use of *for*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a "non-standard use of **for**".

> Please show me the innoculation record for patient 6B.
>
> Please show me the innoculation record of patient 5D.

*for* means "pertaining to".

*of* means "belonging to".

But "belonging" there isn't used in the sense of ownership but in the sense of "uniquely associated with". There's no practical difference *in this context*.

But the two prepositions are not always interchangeable. We could have a context where **for** is correct and **of** is incorrect:

> Here are the dietary protocols we propose for Group A.
>
> Here are the dietary protocols we propose of Group B. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

The verb **propose** drives the choice of preposition.

Or the opposite:

> We should not speak of that.
>
> We should not speak for that. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

The verb **speak** drives the choice, and when it means "discuss" or "mention" the preposition **for** is wrong.

And there are contexts not involving any verb where the one or the other preposition is idiomatic and the other is not. Prepositions are omnipresent and they have developed many different meanings that are available under specific conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You want the licenses belonging to the drivers. The preposition indicating possession is "of".

```
I want the license of your driver.
```

All the parts about plurals and pictures of are irrelevant and don't change the preposition.

If you said "I want the license *for* your driver" that would normally mean you were collecting a license that you were going to give to your driver.